# OpenCV-python and ArUco library estimatePoseSingleMarker() module has no attribute

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

working with OpenCV-python and the aruco library for a tracking project.
The following error is thrown when using

```
rvecs,tvecs = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarker(corners, 0.1765, cameraMatrix, distcoefs)
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'estimatePoseSingleMarker
```

others work fine

`aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.Dict_6x6_250)`

`aruco.DetectParameters_create()`

any idea why its throwing that error?

```
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.2.0-dev'

odroid@odroid:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.12

odroid@odroid:~$ uname -a
Linux odroid 3.10.104-126 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 29 22:24:16 UTC 2016 
armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

edit: its in the help documentation

```
help(cv2.aruco)
Help on module cv2.aruco in cv2:

NAME
    cv2.aruco

FILE
    (built-in)

FUNCTIONS


estimatePoseSingleMarkers(...)
    estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, markerLength, cameraMatrix, 
distCoeffs[, rvecs[, tvecs[, _objPoints]]]) -> rvecs, tvecs, 
_objPoints
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the module is aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers with an s at the end